# "object not found" error when creating a new geom for a package

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Full disclosure: this issue is duplicated on the [ggplot2 google group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ggplot2/OyIsXttba2E/discussion)**

I'm developing a package that makes heavy use of `ggplot2`. I've created my own geom—`geom_rug_alt`—as a way of putting rug fringes on the top/right of the plot instead of the default locations.

My problem is that when `geom_rug_alt()` is defined and called within a [single script](https://gist.github.com/836059), it seems to plot just fine. (Please try it yourself to verify that.) But, in my package `geom_rug_alt()` is defined in one file (`CommonFunctions.R`) and called in another (the `Residuals()` function of larger function `foo.R`). When I call `foo.R` on something, I get this error:

```
Error in geom_rug_alt(aes(x = NULL, y = within.group.residuals, color = factor(within.1.sd.of.the.mean.of.all.residuals)),  : 
object 'GeomRugAlt' not found
```

Now, I've done a couple of things (suggested by Hadley in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ggplot2/uNjqUHkms8M/discussion)) to try to make sure that `geom_rug_alt()` should work properly within the package:

1. I define `GeomRugAlt` as a `proto` object in a file essentially called `CommonFunctions.R` within my package. `CommonFunctions.R` contains lines 3-42 of my [example script](https://gist.github.com/836059).
2. In `CommonFunctions.R`, I was sure to include the `build_accessor()` line for `geom_rug_alt` (line 42 in my [example script](https://gist.github.com/836059)) after the definition of `GeomRugAlt`
3. In the package `DESCRIPTION` file, I have a `collate:` line where `CommonFunctions.R` appears first
4. In the package `DESCRIPTION` file, I have a `LazyLoad: false` line
5. In `CommonFunctions.R`, I included a `require(ggplot2)` call before defining `GeomRugAlt` as a `proto` object.
6. In `foo.R`, I included a `require(ggplot2)` call before calling `geom_rug_alt()` within `Residuals()`.

I'm not sure what else I'm missing. Given that my [example script](https://gist.github.com/836059) runs just fine, I suspect the issue isn't that my geom doesn't work, but that I'm doing something wrong as part of the package development process.

Sorry for duplicating the issue, but I can't seem to find a thorough solution to the problem :-(

Comment: Did you put `export(geom_rug_alt)` in the `NAMESPACE` file?

Comment: @Sascha - that works! Actually, it needs to be `export(GeomRugAlt)`, not `export(geom_rug_alt)`, since `GeomRugAlt` is the object it's not finding. Can you please post that as a answer so I can accept it?

Comment: If your description and namespace files are correct you shouldn't need to manually require ggplot2.  I'd also recommend running `R CMD check`

Comment: @Hadley - after running R CMD check on my package, among many other errors I got this: geom_rug_alt: no visible binding for global variable ‘GeomRugAlt’

Comment: I would suggest fixing all the errors that you can and then making the package source available somewhere.

Comment: You really want R CMD check to run without warnings and errors. Also, in your example scripts `GeomRugAlt` is defined in scripts. Is this also so in the package? If it depends on parameters you should make a wrapping function around it that returns the object, if not then you could simply send it as an RData file with the package right?

Comment: @Sacha - I agree that R CMD check should run without errors, but it also seems to be flagging things that aren't _really_ errors. GeomRugAlt is essentially Hadley's GemRug with two changed numbers; I don't know that it needs a wrapping function. And I'm hesitant to make it an RData file because I don't think that should be necessary.

Comment: @Hadley - Great point. The source for the project's development (dev) branch is at: https://github.com/briandk/granova/tree/dev

Comment: Roadmap: To see the issue manifest, download the branch and source inst/dev.R --- GeomRugAlt is defined in R/granova.R  --- it's used in R/granova.1w.ggplot.R in the Residuals function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `export(GeomRugAlt)` in the `NAMESPACE` file.

Comment: You shouldn't need to export that object.

Comment: @Hadley - I agree. My understanding is that exporting it makes it available to the user, which isn't necessary. We just want foo.R to be able to see GeomRugAlt.