# Why does the first example contained in direct.lable give error?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just run the code that I found in the documentation related to the "direct.label" function. It is the first example:

```
library(ggplot2)
## direct label simple ggplot2 scatterplot
scatter <- qplot(jitter(hwy),jitter(cty),data=mpg,colour=class,
                 main="Fuel efficiency depends on car size")
print(direct.label(scatter))
```

As a result I get the following

> Error in proto(Geom, { : object 'Geom' not found

Any idea???

PS I have already read the following, but they don't help...
["object not found" error when creating a new geom for a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058347/object-not-found-error-when-creating-a-new-geom-for-a-package); 
[geom_rect failure: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'variable' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154293/geom-rect-failure-error-in-evalexpr-envir-enclos-object-variable-not-fo);
[Object not found error with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514345/object-not-found-error-with-ggplot2);
[Error with insertSource(): "object '.cacheOnAssign' not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981005/error-with-insertsource-object-cacheonassign-not-found);
[Fatal Error: Object scala not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395470/fatal-error-object-scala-not-found).

Comment: Works for me with `directlabels_2.6 ggplot2_0.9.1`.  Results of `sessionInfo()` ?